# rails jquery datepicker don't popup TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to get a simple jquery datepicker to work.  I've followed the railscasts episode for it, and even was able to download and get his version working.  I'm not sure why it's not working on my project.  But when I click inside it there is no action and no datepicker popping up.

Console shows the following error:

```
TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
```

More console testing produces:

```
Object[input#datemodel_dated]

>>> $('#datemodel_dated').datepicker

undefined

>>> $('#datemodel_dated').datepicker()

TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

$('#datemodel_dated').datepicker()
```

The erb code:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :dated %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :dated %>
</div>
```

The code pulled from firebug:

```
(function() {
jQuery(function() {
return $('#datemodel_dated').datepicker({
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
});
}).call(this);
```

The coffescript code:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#datemodel_dated').datepicker
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
```

Gemfile

```
group :assets do
  # ...
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
 *= require jquery.ui.datepicker
```

Here is the generated HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Realestate</title>
  <meta name="description" content="...">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> 
  <link href="/assets/jquery.ui.core.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.theme.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/normalize.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/defaults.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/forms.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/blogs.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/borrowers.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/buyers.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/contacts.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/home.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/lenders.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/prospective_properties.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/sellers.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.core.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/datemodels.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/account_members.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/accounts.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/blogs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/borrowers.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/buyers.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/companies.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/contacts.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/customers.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/home.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/journal_entries.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/journals.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/labels.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/leases.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/lenders.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/pages.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/properties.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/prospective_properties.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/rent_logs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/rental_units.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/roles.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/sellers.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/users.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/vendors.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="2kpUpKPNVpHhk9UfDo1CutyVebDLvkwQXUe86qkmIPM=" name="csrf-token" />


  <script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-29109749-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="contents">
  <div class="header">
  <div class="menu">
   ...
  </div>

  <div class="section">
    <div class="column1">
      <img alt="Mini_lion_logo" src="/assets/mini_lion_logo.png" width="100px" />
    </div>
    <div class="left column2">
      <div class = "row">
        <form action="/sellers/new" class="button_to" method="get"><div><input type="submit" value="Sell" /></div></form>
        ...
      </div>
      <div class = "hide">
        <div class="row">
          <form action="/buyers/new" class="button_to" method="get"><div><input type="submit" value="Buy/Rent" /></div></form>
         ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<div class="section">
  <p class="notice"></p>
    <h1>New datemodel</h1>

 <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/datemodels" class="new_datemodel" id="new_datemodel" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="2kpUpKPNVpHhk9UfDo1CutyVebDLvkwQXUe86qkmIPM=" /></div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="datemodel_dated">Dated</label><br />
    <input id="datemodel_dated" name="datemodel[dated]" size="30" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Datemodel" />
  </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

---

And for good measure, i didn't see any problems in the development log, but I might not know what to look for:

```
Started GET "/pm/leases/2/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:45 +0200
Processing by Pm::LeasesController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Lease Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `leases`.* FROM `leases` WHERE `leases`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
  RentalUnit Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `rental_units`.* FROM `rental_units` WHERE `rental_units`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Property Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `properties`.* FROM `properties` WHERE `properties`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered pm/leases/_lease_form.html.erb (142.2ms)
  Rendered pm/leases/_form.html.erb (160.7ms)
  Rendered pm/leases/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (163.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_analytics.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_home_header.html.erb (3.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_home_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 490ms (Views: 205.0ms | ActiveRecord: 9.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/datemodels.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:45 +0200
Served asset /datemodels.js - 200 OK (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery.ui.theme.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:45 +0200
Served asset /jquery.ui.theme.css - 304 Not Modified (2ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:45] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/home.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:45 +0200
Served asset /home.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:45] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/lenders.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:45 +0200
Served asset /lenders.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery.ui.core.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:45 +0200
Served asset /jquery.ui.core.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:45] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
[2013-03-14 18:17:45] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:45 +0200
Served asset /jquery.ui.datepicker.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:45] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/account_members.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:45 +0200
Served asset /account_members.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:45] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/accounts.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:45 +0200
Served asset /accounts.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:45] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/borrowers.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:45 +0200
Served asset /borrowers.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/buyers.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:45 +0200
Served asset /buyers.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:45] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/companies.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:45 +0200
Served asset /companies.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:45] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
[2013-03-14 18:17:45] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/contacts.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:45 +0200
Served asset /contacts.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:45] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/blogs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:45 +0200
Served asset /blogs.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:45] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/home.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:45 +0200
Served asset /home.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:45] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/customers.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:45 +0200
Served asset /customers.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/journal_entries.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /journal_entries.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/journals.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /journals.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/labels.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /labels.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/leases.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /leases.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/lenders.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /lenders.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/properties.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /properties.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/pages.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /pages.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/prospective_properties.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /prospective_properties.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/rent_logs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /rent_logs.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/rental_units.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /rental_units.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/sellers.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /sellers.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/roles.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /roles.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/users.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /users.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/vendors.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /vendors.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/jquery.ui.core.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /jquery.ui.core.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /jquery.ui.datepicker.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/borrowers.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /borrowers.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/buyers.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /buyers.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/contacts.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /contacts.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/prospective_properties.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /prospective_properties.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/blogs.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /blogs.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/forms.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /forms.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /jquery_ujs.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/sellers.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /sellers.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/normalize.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /normalize.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/defaults.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /defaults.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-14 18:17:46 +0200
Served asset /jquery.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)
[2013-03-14 18:17:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

I've read through all the other articles here and couldn't find a solution. I'm sure it's something simple...

I'm using Rails 3.2.12, Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Are you sure the $('#datemodel_dated') returns the element you're wanting?  Is your function inside $(document).ready(... ?

Comment: How would I know?  I don't think it is getting there at all, but firebug finds the actual function...

Comment: You can debug in firefox/firebug. If you go to the "Script" tab, you should be able to select the file in which your function is found and put a break point on it. That's how I usually debug my javascript. You can do something like var temp = $(#myselector); just to make sure it matches. Then at least you can eliminate some uncertainty. Also, is the function in your .erb file? or is it in a separate javascript file? Either way, you should enclose it in $(document).ready(function() {...});

Comment: Datepicker needs a unique id. Are you sure datemodel_dated is unique in your dom.

Comment: Hi user1541507, It is unique for that page.  I made a special test scaffold to test it out.

Comment: Hi Dmoss18,  it's in a coffee script file.  I put a break point in the file and it appears to load it. but when i test it in the console I get the following `Object[input#datemodel_dated]

>>> $('#datemodel_dated').datepicker

undefined

>>> $('#datemodel_dated').datepicker()

TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

$('#datemodel_dated').datepicker()`, I'll put it in the question so that it's easier to read.

Comment: I'm trying the following code in the application.js file `$(document).ready(function() {
(function() {
    jQuery(function() {
    return $('#datemodel_dated').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
    });
    }).call(this);
});`

Comment: Looks like your selector is working.  I would change the document.ready to this, you have too many "function" statements in there: `$(document).ready(function() { $('#datemodel_dated').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }); });`  You shouldn't need to return anything, and you shouldn't need .call()

Comment: That is cleaner, but it's still telling me .datepicker is not a function... I need to play with it later, but it seems that the library isn't getting loaded even though I see it in the header files and seem to be able to see the jquery libary in the firebox script area.

Comment: i don't see your application.js being loaded in the log

Comment: i am getting same error.. :( help me out please. :(